# How to make half-page Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make this Bootstrap 3 carousel half-page, but I don't see what I have to change in order to make it do so. It looks fine in a small window, but when I expand the window to full screen, the carousel literally takes up the entire page. How do I make the Bootstrap carousel half-page on a full window?

I tried putting it in a header, but that did not work.

```html
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <!--Indicators-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!--/.Indicators-->
  <!--Slides-->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="view">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="write2.jpg"
          alt="First slide">
        <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="h3-responsive">Light mask</h3>
        <p>First text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <!--Mask color-->
      <div class="view">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="step21.jpg"
          alt="Second slide">
        <div class="mask rgba-black-strong"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="h3-responsive">Strong mask</h3>
        <p>Secondary text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <!--Mask color-->
      <div class="view">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="read.jpg"
          alt="Third slide">
        <div class="mask rgba-black-slight"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="h3-responsive">Slight mask</h3>
        <p>Third text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.Slides-->
  <!--Controls-->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  <!--/.Controls-->
</div>
```

UPDATE! The carousel is now half-screen, but as the window expands, the images are getting more and more zoomed in. I used the CSS Code, as suggested by a user, to make the carousel half-page, but again, as the window expands, the images are getting zoomed in. How do I not get the images to zoom in as the window expands?

```css
.carousel-inner{
    height: 50vh;
}


.item img{
    height: 100% !important;
    width:  100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question. The jsfiddle which you have provided was bootstrap 4 and the question you were asking is about bootstrap 3. Which version are you looking for?

Comment: I prefer Bootstrap 3, but I don't know how to manually add it to my code so I don't have to download it. The instructions with Bootstrap 4 were easy, so I went with it. But I do prefer Bootstrap 4, but if you can somehow show an example for Bootstrap 3 as well, that would be nice.

Comment: check the below snippet

Comment: I tried looking at the W3 tutorial for adding Bootstrap 3 using CDN, but that did not work.

Comment: I did understand what you were talking about. Bootstrap 3 CDN works fine and my previous answer was Bootstrap 3. Your Jsfiddle example was of Bootstrap 4, Don't try to club V3 and V4 as they are different .

Comment: The below code snippet gave a much better result than yesterday. The images are still zooming in, but it is less than before. Any suggestions?

Comment: `object-fit: cover;` replace with `object-fit: fill;`

Comment: Much more better. When I expand the window, the entire image fits the carousel. The images do look a bit stretched than its original, but is that a problem with the images? Also, when if I make the window fill up 40% of the screen horizontally, the carousel doesn't fill up the entire page. The original size of the image is 640px x 480px. Is that the image's fault or the code's fault. Any suggestions on solving both issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** to  Bootstrap 4 as per your jsFiddle which you have mentioned in the comment below

```css
    .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item .view {
      height: 50vh!important;
    }

    .carousel-item img {
      object-fit: cover;
      width:100%!important;
      height: 100% !important;
    }

    .content h1 {
      font-size: 55px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
      .content h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
      .content h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }

      
    }

    .content h5 {
      font-size: 23px;
      margin-left: 80px;
      margin-right: 80px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
      .content h5 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px
      }

    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
      .content h5 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #515151;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="homepage.html">Title</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText"
      aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </nav>

  

    <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" style="height:50vh">
      <!--Indicators-->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!--/.Indicators-->
      <!--Slides-->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="view">
            <img  src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="New york"
               alt="First slide">
            <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3 class="h3-responsive">Light mask</h3>
            <p>First text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <!--Mask color-->
          <div class="view">
            <img  src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="New york"
              alt="Second slide">
            <div class="mask rgba-black-strong"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3 class="h3-responsive">Strong mask</h3>
            <p>Secondary text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <!--Mask color-->
          <div class="view">
            <img  src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="New york"
               alt="Third slide">
            <div class="mask rgba-black-slight"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3 class="h3-responsive">Slight mask</h3>
            <p>Third text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/.Slides-->
      <!--Controls-->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
      <!--/.Controls-->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The below works for Bootstrap 3

```
.carousel-inner{
    height: 50vh;
}
.item.active{
  height: 50vh!important;
}
.item img{
 object-fit:cover;
 height:100%!important;
}
```

Comment: This somewhat works - it can expand the carousel half-screen, but it makes the images too zoomed in. When I shrink the window to a smaller size, the images look perfect. When I try to make the window bigger, the images will expand along with it. How can I make the images in the carousel not zoom in when the window is expanded? If you need, I can share with you the images. Thank you for reading!

Comment: @ComputerCoder check it now. Updated the answer

Comment: The images are still zooming in, but the captions are now appearing when the window expands with the code: .item.active{
  height: 50vh!important;
}  That is some progress! The code you provided is a faulty W3 tutorial, as the arrows don't even work. Any suggestions on making the images remain neutral when the window expands? Also, could you base your suggestions more from my code? I think that way we can solve this issue.

Comment: If you want complete width to 100% you need to make your images in a way that it meets your requirement. Try using `contain` and `fit` instead of `cover`. You will understand what's happening around.

Comment: I honestly like the organize size of the images and don't want to alter them. I tried using contain. It doesn't work. Is there any other suggestions? I don't really see how the images are zooming in by itself when the window expands.

Comment: Because the images are set to width of 100% . Check by applying `fill` you will get the result but you will feel that images get streched out.  So cover scales the image and fit's the div accordingly

Comment: I can see it now, but as I change the width, the image doesn't take up the entire screen as the window gets bigger. This is the css so far: .carousel-inner{
    height: 50vh;
}
.carousel-item.active{
  height: 50vh!important;
}
.carousel-item .view img{
 object-fit:cover;
 height:100%!important;
 width:100%!important;
}  Any suggestions on making the width to a certain number that will make the images not zoom in as the window expands?

Comment: Width should be 100% to fill entire div. I mean carousel

Comment: I tried doing that with this updated css code, but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions? .carousel-inner{
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel-item.active{
  height: 50vh!important;
  
}
.carousel-item .view img{
 object-fit:cover;
 height:100%!important;
 
}

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle fiddle and update your code there

Comment: If you want me to attach the images, let me know

Comment: check the code now. You have mentioned bootstrap 3 and you are using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

The below works for Bootstrap 4. In other to prevent the image from zooming in on smaller screens, you have to use CSS media queries to adjust the height of the carousel items. The height for smaller device screens should be smaller than the half value you set for large screens. So if you set a Viewport height to 50%(50vh), the viewport height for a smaller screen should be something like 30%(30vh). Because smaller screens(mobile devices) have longer heights(viewport height) than bigger screens that have wider screen width(viewport width). So it is more of ratio and proportion here.

The below code should work in your case.

```css
    /* Carousel 1/2 of screen */
    
    .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item .view {
        height: 50vh!important;
      }
      .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item  {
        height: 50vh!important;
      }
    
      .carousel-item img {
        object-fit: cover;
        width:100%!important;
        height: 100% !important;
      }
    
      .content h1 {
        font-size: 55px;
      }
      .content h5 {
        font-size: 23px;
        margin-left: 80px;
        margin-right: 80px;
      }
    
      /*MEDIA QUERIES RESPONSIVE DESIGN */
    
    /* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        /* Carousel 1/2 of screen */
    
    .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item .view {
        height: 30vh!important;
      }
      .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item  {
        height: 30vh!important;
      }
    
      .carousel-item img {
        object-fit: cover;
        width:100%!important;
        height: 100% !important;
      }
    } 
    
    /* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
            /* Carousel 1/2 of screen */
    
    .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item .view {
        height: 30vh!important;
      }
      .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item  {
        height: 30vh!important;
      }
    
      .carousel-item img {
        object-fit: cover;
        width:100%!important;
        height: 100% !important;
      }
    
    } 
    
    /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* Carousel 1/2 of screen */
    
    .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item .view {
        height: 30vh!important;
      }
      .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item  {
        height: 30vh!important;
      }
    
      .carousel-item img {
        object-fit: cover;
        width:100%!important;
        height: 100% !important;
      }
    } 
    
    /* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        /* Carousel 1/2 of screen */
    
    .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item .view {
        height: 50vh!important;
      }
      .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item  {
        height: 50vh!important;
      }
    
      .carousel-item img {
        object-fit: cover;
        width:100%!important;
        height: 100% !important;
      }
    
    } 
    
    /* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        /* Carousel 1/2 of screen */
    
    .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item .view {
        height: 50vh!important;
      }
      .carousel-item.active, .carousel-item  {
        height: 50vh!important;
      }
    
      .carousel-item img {
        object-fit: cover;
        width:100%!important;
        height: 100% !important;
      }
    
    }
```